# CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)' when playing video

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer, xcode9

I am generate list of thumbails of videos on iOS:

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:cell.frame.size.width, height:cell.frame.size.height))
    let image = uiImageArray[indexPath.row]
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

    cell.addSubview(imageView)
    return cell
}
```

When user clicks image i want to play video :

```
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    self.assetToNav = indexPath.item
    let data = self.assestArray[self.assetToNav]

    self.playVideo(view: self, videoAsset: data)
}
  func playVideo (view: UIViewController, videoAsset: PHAsset) {

        guard (videoAsset.mediaType == .video) else {
            print("Not a valid video media type")
            return
        }

        PHCachingImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: videoAsset, options: nil) { (asset, audioMix, args) in
            let asset = asset as! AVURLAsset

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let player = AVPlayer(url: asset.url)
                let playerViewController = VideoPlayerViewController()
                playerViewController.player = player
                view.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                    playerViewController.player!.play()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When videos start to playing i see in console error:

[framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'

I am beginner wth swift programming , please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496089/how-to-debug-cuicatalog-invalid-asset-name-supplied-null)